# merged html files - not removing head/body of each file can slow loading?

Tags: html, browser

I merged many html files (e-pub chapters) into one big html file. I did not remove anything. Loading is slow but, after loading, browser handle the huge web-page very well. I ask if it is possible that loading is slow because of not cutting head/body tags where not right.

Comment: Whats the file size and where are you loading it from (network vs disk)? It is an invalid HTML format to have multiple head or body sections, though some browsers may render it.

Comment: the html alone is 3Mb, it is loaded from local hard-drive. the browsers render it. I want to know if this could be slowing the loading time or, better to say the rendering time.

Answer (score 0):

An HTML document can only have a single `<html>` element, containing a single `<head>` and a single `<body>` element respectively.

Comment: I purged the file, now it is like you say. IE loads the html in a reasonable time, then ask me if it has to allow ActiveX content (I put a slider and a javascript function): after this delay occurs.